# Speeding up evaluation of multilabel classifier

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, spacy

I've got a text categorizer in `spacy` for a multi label classification problem. Evaluating it takes a *really* long time.

It's not getting the probabilities that takes a long time, but calculating log loss precision, recall and fscore.

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss
import time


def evaluate(
    nlp, texts, cats, labels, threshold=0.3, beta=0.5, batch_size=8
):
    t0 = time.time()
    docs = nlp.pipe(texts, batch_size=batch_size)
    t1 = time.time()
    pred_probs = np.array([list(doc.cats.values()) for doc in docs])

    avg_log_loss = log_loss(cats, pred_probs)
    results = {'log_loss': avg_log_loss}
    y_pred = pred_probs > thresh
    prc, rec, fscore, _ = precision_recall_fscore_support(
      y_true=cats, y_pred=y_pred, beta=beta, average='micro', warn_for=set()
    )
    results[f'f{beta}_{thresh}'] = fscore
    results[f'prc_{thresh}'] = prc
    results[f'rec_{thresh}'] = rec
    t2 = time.time()
    print(f"Used {t1-t0} on predicting; {t2-t1} on scoring")
    return results
```

which outputs `Used 4.76837158203125e-06 on predicting; 377.1225287914276 on scoring`
Any way to speed this up?

Comment: do you have a multilabel classification problem = one instance can get assigned to several classes? or a multiclass classification = one instance get assigned to one class, but you can have more then two (binary) classes ?

Comment: @PV8 it's a multilabel problem

Comment: This is more of a scikit-learn problem than a spacy problem, but on the spacy side of things: `doc.cats` is a dict, so `doc.cats.values()` is not necessarily going to have a predictable order.

Comment: @aab Dict order is guaranteed as of Python 3.7. On further inspection, this *is* a spacy 'problem' not a sklearn problem, as `nlp.pipe` returns a generator. All the compute time of Spacys ML model is thus spent inside `pred_probs = ..` since the docs are lazily generated. Thus this is not a problem with evaluation, just a big and slow ML model.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I used `list(nlp.pipe())` in a mock-up test case and forgot about that.